# SQLSTATE=23514 : Facing error on Set integrity

Tags: db2, constraints

Can someone suggest me what is the problem, why I am not able to enable integrity, although no constraint found with name of CATEGORY.

`create function FCOK_ACCOUNT_CATEGORY_C2(xmlrecord XML) returns integer language sql contains sql no external action deterministic return xmlcast(xmlquery('$d/row/c2' passing xmlrecord as "d") as integer);`

`reorg table FCOK_ACCOUNT_TEST inplace`

`db2pd -db admindb –reorg`

Database Member 0 -- Database ADMINDB -- Active -- Up 10 days 03:14:17 -- Date 2021-07-26-19.28.05.648688

Table Reorg Information:
Address            TbspaceID TableID PartID MasterTbs MasterTab TableName          Type    IndexID    TempSpaceID
0x0A001F00174DF588 4         21566   n/a    n/a       n/a       FCOK_ACCOUNT       Offline 0          4
0x0A001F0027981508 3         26880   n/a    n/a       n/a       FCOK_ACCOUNT_TEST  Online  0          3

Table Reorg Stats:
Address            TableName          Start               End                 PhaseStart          MaxPhase   Phase      CurCount   MaxCount   Status  Completion
0x0A001F00174DF588 FCOK_ACCOUNT       07/16/2021 18:38:46 07/16/2021 18:43:15 07/16/2021 18:39:40 3          IdxRecreat 0          0          Done    0
0x0A001F0027981508 FCOK_ACCOUNT_TEST  07/26/2021 18:13:16 07/26/2021 18:14:38 n/a                 n/a        n/a        0          0          Done    0
bash-4.2$

`set integrity for FCOK_ACCOUNT_TEST off;`

`ALTER TABLE FCOK_ACCOUNT_TEST ADD CATEGORY INTEGER generated always as (FCOK_ACCOUNT_CATEGORY_C2(XMLRECORD))`

`set integrity for FCOK_ACCOUNT_TEST immediate checked;`

`db2 "set integrity for DB2ADMIN.FCOK_ACCOUNT_TEST immediate checked"`

**DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL3603N  Integrity processing through the SET INTEGRITY statement has found
an integrity violation involving a constraint, a unique index, a generated
column, or an index over an XML column. The associated object is identified by
"DB2ADMIN.FCOK_ACCOUNT_TEST.CATEGORY".  SQLSTATE=23514**
bash-4.2$

`bash-4.2$ db2 "select TYPE, ENFORCED from SYSCAT.TABCONST where CONSTNAME='CATEGORY'"`

TYPE ENFORCED

---

0 record(s) selected.

`bash-4.2$ db2 "select COLSEQ,COLNAME from SYSCAT.KEYCOLUSE where CONSTNAME='CATEGORY'"`

COLSEQ COLNAME

---

0 record(s) selected.

`bash-4.2$ db2 "reorg table db2admin.FCOK_ACCOUNT_TEST inplace"`

**SQL0668N  Operation not allowed for reason code "1" on table
"DB2ADMIN.FCOK_ACCOUNT_TEST".  SQLSTATE=57016**

Comment: The SQL3603N means that the  UDF is not behaving in the way you expected for newly column CATEGORY.  This can happen if either your UDF has a coding error, or your XML data values are not what your code assumes. Check the Db2-server diagnostics to see if there is a RID mentioned (or increase diagnostic level to encourage it) then manually run the UDF against that row (i.e not within a constraint).

Comment: @mao, No issue in UDF code as running manually found results as expected.

Comment: **db2 "SELECT   CAST(RECID AS VARCHAR(20)) REC, FCOK_ACCOUNT_CATEGORY_C2(XMLRECORD) UDF, CAST(CATEGORY AS VARCHAR(20)) Actual_Value FROM db2admin.V_FCOK_ACCOUNT  WHERE RECID ='PKR1500400019001'"**

`REC                  UDF         ACTUAL_VALUE
-------------------- ----------- --------------------
PKR1500400019001           15004 15004`

  1 record(s) selected.

bash-4.2$

Comment: After running following command 
**db2 "SET INTEGRITY FOR FCOK_ACCOUNT_TEST ALL IMMEDIATE UNCHECKED"**
I am able to access table but value in **CATEGORY COLUMN** shows **0**.

`db2 "SELECT   CAST(RECID AS VARCHAR(20)) REC, FCOK_ACCOUNT_CATEGORY_C2(XMLRECORD) UDF , CATEGORY FROM db2admin.FCOK_ACCOUNT_TEST  WHERE RECID ='PKR1500400019001'"`

REC                  UDF         CATEGORY
-------------------- ----------- -----------
PKR1500400019001           15004           0

  1 record(s) selected.

Comment: the UDF is working except when it's not... Don't use comments for new info because they lose formatting and are not searchable, instead edit your question to add new details. There's at least one row in the table where the UDF does not work, apparently.